# How to get gridview to change pages faster

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

GridView in my ASP.NET application is working very slowly when changing pages. I know that this is most probably caused by a lot of data being pooled out of database each time page is updated but I don’t know how to fix this since I’m not to ASP.NET.

My current configuration is GridView with ObjectDateSource and paging enabled. I don’t have any code behind or anything similar. ObjectDataSource is bined to typed data set.

Comment: Do you have some more information on what you are displaying. Have you tried profiling and determining what is the slow part. If it is the sql then that is one thing. If it is the actual rendering on the browser that is another. I would recommend using MiniProfiler to see where it is slow http://miniprofiler.com/

Comment: Do you page the `GridView` only or also the data? You can use `ROW_NUMBER` on MS SQL-Server. I would suggest to have a look at this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb445504.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the cause of this – it’s the fact that you have to get all the data from database even if you only want to display one small part. For example, you retrieve 5000 rows from DB only to display 15 rows in current page.

Solution for this is implementing custom paging.

In order to get this to work with your current configuration you’ll need to update your current select method to accept the starting index and maximum number of rows input parameters and also update following properties in your grid view

“StartRowIndexParameterName”, “MaximumRowsParameterName”, “SelectCountMethod”.

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx)  is a great article that covers what you need but there are also a lot of topics here on StackOverflow that cover this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I found the same problem and implemented a custom gridview which is now opensource, you can find it here https://github.com/vcliment89/GridViewEX. You don't need to implement all the gridview but there's an example of a custom pager on the demo project.